# How to set a typedef to a variable in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

Regular use of a variable in Typescript as a class property:

```
public myVar: String = 'text';
```

Regular use of a variable and type in a class method's parameter:

```
public myMethod(paramVar: String): void { /* code*/ }
```

What I need to achieve is to set a type to a variable and use it to replace fixed parameter type of the method, or (if I need) to replace the return type. **How can I do it?**

Would it look like, for example?:

```
public myType: Type = String;                         // string here is just a class example (it could be DiceType, CustomString etc.)

public myMethod1(paramVar: myType): void { /* code */ }   
public myMethod2(): myType { 
   return new myType()                                // <= can I do that too?
}
```

Comment: the generic **any** is not an option at the moment, as it would became just JS again.

Comment: Are you asking for a type alias? http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh YES! That Solves my Quest! Thank You!!

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh don't you want to write your comment as an answer?